# Is it possible to execute a function after return statement in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a time-consuming function that I want to run however, I don't want the user to keep waiting. This is my current code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, session
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
   my_function():
      """
      execute codde
      """
   my_function()
   return render_template('index.html')
```

I want to run something like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
   my_function():
      """
      execute codde
      """
 return render_template('index.html')  
 my_function()
```

The `myFunction` is in the same page and it works perfectly fine.
Obviously this isn't possible but I just want to know how to `return render_template('index.html')` first and then call the function?

Comment: Basically you want to return from function but don't really, am I right?

Comment: Sounds like you want to kick off an asynchronous function.

Comment: I edited the post so everyone understands what I am trying to do.

Comment: Did you mean: `ret = render_template('index.html'); my_function(); return ret`?

Comment: @quamrana, I want to return render template and then execute the function

Comment: There is no way with a synchronous call, just like that.

Comment: There's no difference between returning something, then calling a function or calling a function and then returning something.

Comment: you may want to check this article :https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/flask-rq-task-queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`flask-executor`](https://flask-executor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides a lightweight way to do this.

In your case, it might look like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, session

app = Flask(__name__)
executor = Executor(app)

@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    executor.submit(my_function)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

`my_function` will be executed asynchronously, and `index` will continue to run immediately, letting you respond to the request by rendering the template without waiting for `my_function` to finish running.

If you need more guarantees, like scalability (tasks could execute on other computers) or reliability (tasks still execute if the webserver dies), you could look into something like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) or [RQ](https://python-rq.org/). Those tools are powerful, but generally require much more configuration then the `flask-executor` example above.

Comment: I keep getting this error: 
TypeError: Executor() takes no arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can "yield" it.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, session
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
   my_function():
      """
      execute codde
      """
   yield render_template('index.html')
   my_function()
```

In this way the function "return" something but will not stop and call the "my_function" function and all the code after this.

For more info I suggest [THIS LINK](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-yield-keyword-instead-return-keyword-python/) from GeekForGeek

Comment: I'm not sure `yield` does what you think it does. It certainly converts a function into a generator. I don't know whether `flask` knows about generators.

Comment: @quamrana, yield doesn't work with flask, I tried but thanks for the solution.